# Не понимаю как расположить кнопки по краям от лого

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, веб-сайт

Верстаю сайт по макету, в навигационном меню лого расположено между пунктами меню. Верстаю в первый раз по гайдам из ютуба(до этого только совмещение ужже навёрстанного с моим сайтом). Проблема заключается в том, что как бы я не пытался расположить текст по краям, он всегда находится в одной группе под лого. (делаю в css и html)
ниже одна из попыток

```
.header-line {
    padding-top: 43px;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    height:100px ;
    
}
```

ниже ещё пример, уже из гайда(в нём лого находится слева от пунктов)

```
.header-line {
    padding-top: 43px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}
```

а вот так выглядит сам хедер на сайте[image: отображение на сайте]

и вот сам код хедера в html

```
<div class="header">
     <div class = 'container'>
     <div class = 'header-line'>
          <div class = 'header-logo'>
              <img src="logo.png">
           <div class = 'nav'>
              <a class='nav-item' href="*">Расписание</a>
              <a class='nav-item' href="*">Цены</a>
             <a class='nav-item' href="*">Каюты</a>
              <a class='nav-item' href="*">Галерея</a>
              <a class='nav-item' href="*">О Нас</a>
         <div class="phone">
         <div class="number">+7 (777)-777-77-77
             </div>
         </div>
```

буду премного благодарен за любую помощь!

Comment: чтобы лого можно было разместить среди элементов, у них должен быть один родитель. во флексах есть параметр `order`, с помощью которого можно указать позицию элемента во флекс-контейнере

Comment: Вы хотите, чтобы в центре было лого, а справа и слева пункты меню?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сорри, с телефона было неудобно писать. Скопируйте и вставьте в редактор. Примерно такой результат Вы хотели?

`<!DOCTYPE html>`

`<html lang="ru">`

`<head>`

`<meta charset="UTF-8>`

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">`

`<title>Расписание</title>`

`<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-9ndCyUaIbzAi2FUVXJi0CjmCapSmO7SnpJef0486qhLnuZ2cdeRhO02iuK6FUUVM" crossorigin="anonymous">`

`</head>`

`<body>`

`<div class="container-fluid">`

`<div class="row">`

`<div class="col-12">`

`<img src="https://avatars.mds.yandex.net/i?id=af94e955088e768e0b17a6ce2f7ce00e_l-4428735-images-thumbs&n=13" class="rounded mx-auto d-block" width="50px" alt="logo">`

`</div>`

`</div>`

`<div class="row">`

`<div class="col-8">`

`<ul class="nav">`

`<li class="nav-item">`

`<a class="nav-link" aria-current="page" href="#">Расписание</a>`

`</li>`

`<li class="nav-item">`

`<a class="nav-link" href="#">Цены</a>`

`</li>`

`<li class="nav-item">`

`<a class="nav-link" href="#">Каюты</a>`

`</li>`

`</ul>`

`</div>`

`<div class="col-4">`

`<ul class="nav">`

`<li class="nav-item">`

`<a class="nav-link" href="#">Галерея</a>`

`</li>`

`<li class="nav-item">`

`<a class="nav-link" href="#">О нас</a>`

`</li>`

`</ul>`

`</div>`

`</div>`

`</div>`

`<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-geWF76RCwLtnZ8qwWowPQNguL3RmwHVBC9FhGdlKrxdiJJigb/j/68SIy3Te4Bkz" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>`

`</body>`

`</html>`